# JPA StoredProcedureQuery get wrong values starting from parameters

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, stored-procedures

I got a problem with JPA `StoredProcedureQuery`, the problem consist I'm getting different values unexpected. In MySQL workbench I execute the stored procedure called `sp_GET_Result` that it is waiting two parameters called `startDate` and `endDate`.

For instance:

[image]

[image]

And the results are like:

[image]

So far it's ok, but the problem is when I call it from Java JPA.

This is my java routine

[image]

I'm getting this results:

[**2017-01-31**, 2017-02-01, 2017-02-02, 2017-02-03, 2017-02-04, 2017-02-05, 2017-02-06, 2017-02-07, 2017-02-08, 2017-02-09, 2017-02-10, 2017-02-11, 2017-02-12, 2017-02-13, 2017-02-14, 2017-02-15, 2017-02-16, 2017-02-17, 2017-02-18, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-20, 2017-02-21, 2017-02-22, 2017-02-23, 2017-02-24, 2017-02-25, 2017-02-26, **2017-02-27**]

I think the problem not is with the store procedure if not with the parameters that java is sending.
Because I did a try out printing the parameters that Java is sending and MySQL is receiving and the results are like:
starDate , endDate
[2017-01-31, 2017-02-27] but Why?? because I'm sending from 2017-02-01 to 2017-02-28.

The problem not is the store procedure, the really problem is the variation in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your **JDBC driver** converts your input dates into the UTC format, which is used by database. Or via versa, your response dates are converted into your local timezone. Check the **JDBC driver** setting: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html.

Comment: Thank you for your help !!!, You gave me references to find the real problem. And the problem was the server where mysql is allocated. MySQL had the timezone the server UTC and Java was sending the input dates in CST and for that reason the response from the MySQL were wrong.